# What causes "Error retrieving REPORT: The server unexpectedly closed the connection"?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN. I've been able to successfully checkout my code 1 out of 7 attempts. **What happens** is I begin to "checkout" out the code using TortoiseSVN, I can see the files being added both in SVN and by looking at the folder they are going to, and then a couple of minutes later I get this error.

Comment: What TortoiseSVN version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use up-to-date TortoiseSVN / svn.exe client. Right now it's [TortoiseSVN 1.9](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).
2. Check your antivirus. Add TortoiseSVN / svn.exe to exclusions list of this antivirus and temporarily disable it. See whether it helps.

Comment: I updated to 1.9.3 and I was able to completely checkout my branch twice in a row. I'm going to say it's fixed. Could you explain why such a small change from 1.8.8 to 1.9.3 would do this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @WhoYaGonnaCall *small change?* 1 major update from 1.8 to 1.9 release and 6 patch updates between? I wouldn't call it a *small change*. Check the changelog for SVN: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.9.3/CHANGES

Comment: Sorry for calling it a small change. Could you add some insight into why 1.8.8 was having issues checking-out from SVN. Thank you.

Comment: @WhoYaGonnaCall I can't tell for sure. It seems that there was a bug in Subversion or one of its components (e.g. Serf lib) that was solved in later updates. I can't point to a particular changelog entry for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that your svn version is more advanced than the one that created the repo you are trying to update.

If you are not using Tortoise but just the command line svn try

```
svn upgrade
```

inside the repo folder